# VBA to save data on another sheet

Tags: excel, save, vba

I am using a VBA to copy and save data on another sheet namely 'Data'. The data saved but first time it saved at wrong place i.e. Range. It jumps 50 rows. After second time and onwards it saved at right places. Could you tell me my mistakes[image: ![Its the screenshot of 'Data' Sheet]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b52rP.png)

```
Sub Save_Click()

' Save Pay_Slip on "Data"Sheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet
Dim LR As Long
Dim last As Long

Sheets("Data").Unprotect Password:=""
Sheets("Pay_Slip").Unprotect Password:=""

LR = Sheets("Pay_Slip").Range("B500").End(xlUp).Row
last = Sheets("Data").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set copySheet = Worksheets("Pay_Slip")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Data")

Sheets("Data").Range("A" & last + 3).Value = 
Sheets("Pay_Slip").Range("Y3").Value
Sheets("Data").Range("B" & last + 3).Value = 
Sheets("Pay_Slip").Range("T3:V3").Value
Sheets("Data").Range("C" & last + 3).Value = 
Sheets("Pay_Slip").Range("I2:K2").Value

copySheet.Range("A5" & ":AI" & LR + 2).Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial 
xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Sheets("Pay_Slip").Range("X2").Value = _
Sheets("Pay_Slip").Range("X2").Value + 1

Sheets("Pay_Slip").Protect Password:=""
Sheets("Data").Protect Password:=""

End Sub
```

Comment: I seems that It finds last used cell in 4th column(E) instead of last blank cells of the column!

Comment: That's because your "last" variable is set to look at column E.  Either change that to a column that is populated for every row, or try using UsedRange.Rows.Count.  Also, edit your code so it shows up properly and you'll probably get more responses.

Comment: Definitely use the UsedRange.Rows.Count as @acvbasql suggested.  That will give you the absolute last row that is not blank.

Answer (score 0):

For the first time its placing the data in the range("A4") and so on, this is happening because you are writing statements individually, and then you have written code to copy the data from range("A5" & ":AI" & LR + 2) so its placing data in correct position. If you want to paste data in sheet "Data" in range("W2") then ignore the individual statements.